# Different NSMutableDictionary formatting for JSON between apps

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Okay, so here's the issue.  I have two apps that need to package up JSON request data and send it to the server.  The issue is that when I print the result from my NSMutableDictionary to be used as the JSON request body, I get different results from the different apps.  I have the data formatted the same way, and can't figure out why I'm getting different results.  Possibly it is a compiler setting?  Or iOS version?  Not sure what to even check at this point.

```
        requestDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        // Set Lead type
        NSString *leadType = @"lead";
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadType forKey:@"type"];

        // Set Lead status
        NSString *leadStatus = @"1";
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadStatus forKey:@"status"];

        // Set Lead email
        if([data objectForKey:@"email"]){
            m_leadEmail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[data objectForKey:@"email"], @"value", nil], nil];
            [requestDictionary setObject:m_leadEmail forKey:@"field_lead_email"];
        }
        else{
            NSMutableArray *leadEmail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"testcompany@tester.com", @"value", nil], nil];
            [requestDictionary setObject:leadEmail forKey:@"field_lead_email"];
        }

        NSLog(@"Email field: %@", m_leadEmail);

        // Set Lead source
        NSMutableArray *leadSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"19018", @"nid", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadSource forKey:@"field_lead_source"];

        // Set Lead event
        NSMutableArray *leadEvent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"19018", @"nid", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadEvent forKey:@"field_lead_event"];


        // Set Lead tags
        NSMutableArray *leadTags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadTags forKey:@"field_lead_tags"];

        // Set Lead title
        NSMutableArray *leadTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"My Title", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadTitle forKey:@"field_lead_title"];

        // Set Lead first name
        if([data objectForKey:@"firstName"]){
            NSMutableArray *leadFirstName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[data objectForKey:@"firstName"], @"value", nil], nil];
            [requestDictionary setObject:leadFirstName forKey:@"field_lead_first_name"];
        }
        else{
            NSMutableArray *leadFirstName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"TestLead", @"value", nil], nil];
            [requestDictionary setObject:leadFirstName forKey:@"field_lead_first_name"];
        }

        // Set Lead last name
        if([data objectForKey:@"lastName"]){
            NSMutableArray *leadLastName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[data objectForKey:@"lastName"], @"value", nil], nil];
            [requestDictionary setObject:leadLastName forKey:@"field_lead_last_name"];
        }
        else{
            NSMutableArray *leadLastName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Tester", @"value", nil], nil];
            [requestDictionary setObject:leadLastName forKey:@"field_lead_last_name"];
        }

        // Set Lead middle name
        NSMutableArray *leadMidName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"MiddleName", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadMidName forKey:@"field_lead_middle_name"];

        // Set Lead suffix
        NSMutableArray *leadSuffix = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mr.", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadSuffix forKey:@"field_lead_suffix"];

        // Set Lead job title
        NSMutableArray *leadJobTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Job Title", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadJobTitle forKey:@"field_lead_job_title"];

        // Set Lead company
        NSMutableArray *leadCompany = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"MyCompany", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadCompany forKey:@"field_lead_company"];

        // Set Lead division
        NSMutableArray *leadDivision = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"My Division", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadDivision forKey:@"field_lead_division"];

        // Set Lead add1
        NSMutableArray *leadAdd1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"123 Anywhere Street", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadAdd1 forKey:@"field_lead_add1"];

        // Set Lead add2
        NSMutableArray *leadAdd2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Address 2", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadAdd2 forKey:@"field_lead_add2"];

        // Set Lead city
        NSMutableArray *leadCity = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Austin", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadCity forKey:@"field_lead_city"];

        // Set Lead state
        NSMutableArray *leadState = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"TX", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadState forKey:@"field_lead_state"];

        // Set Lead country
        NSMutableArray *leadCountry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"USA", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadCountry forKey:@"field_lead_country"];

        // Set Lead phone1
        if([data objectForKey:@"phoneNumber"]){
            NSMutableArray *leadPhone1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[data objectForKey:@"phoneNumber"], @"value", nil], nil];
            [requestDictionary setObject:leadPhone1 forKey:@"field_lead_phone_1"];
        }
        else{
            NSMutableArray *leadPhone1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"555-555-1212", @"value", nil], nil];
            [requestDictionary setObject:leadPhone1 forKey:@"field_lead_phone_1"];
        }

        // Set Lead phone2
        NSMutableArray *leadPhone2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"555-555-1234", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadPhone2 forKey:@"field_lead_phone_2"];

        // Set Lead fax
        NSMutableArray *leadFax = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"555-555-1111", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadFax forKey:@"field_lead_fax"];

        // Set Lead website
        NSMutableArray *leadWebsite = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"http://sparksight.com", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadWebsite forKey:@"field_lead_website"];

        // Set Lead zip
        NSMutableArray *leadZip = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"78759", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadZip forKey:@"field_lead_zip"];

        // Set Lead RFID
        NSMutableArray *leadRFID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"RFIDTAG", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadRFID forKey:@"field_rfid_id"];

        // Set Lead phonetic
        NSMutableArray *leadPhonetic = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"PRONOUNCE", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadPhonetic forKey:@"field_lead_phonetic"];

        // Set lead field status
        NSMutableArray *leadFieldStatus = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"2", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadFieldStatus forKey:@"field_lead_status"];

        // Set Lead bizcard
        NSMutableArray *leadBizCard = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Biz Card", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadBizCard forKey:@"field_business_card"];

        // Set Lead bizcard image
        NSMutableArray *leadBizImg = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadBizImg forKey:@"field_business_card_image"];

        // Set Lead qualification
        NSMutableArray *leadQualification = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Priority 1 \u2013 Hot Lead, immediate action is required", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadQualification forKey:@"field_lead_qualification"];

        // Set lead subscribe
        NSMutableArray *leadSubscribe = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"SUBSCRIBE to Newsletter", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadSubscribe forKey:@"field_lead_subscribe"];

        // Set Lead contact
        NSMutableArray *leadContact = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"contact later", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadContact forKey:@"field_lead_contact"];

        // Set Lead notes
        NSMutableArray *leadNotes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"<p>\r\n\tNotes here!</p>\r\n", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadNotes forKey:@"field_lead_notes"];

        // Set Lead badge string
        NSMutableArray *leadBadge = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"BADGE123", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadBadge forKey:@"field_badge_string"];

        // Set Lead quiz string
        NSMutableArray *leadQuiz = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"<p>\r\n\tquiz results!</p>\r\n", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadQuiz forKey:@"field_quiz_string"];

        // Set Lead services
        NSMutableArray *leadServices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Services Field", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadServices forKey:@"field_services"];

        // Set Lead sales rep
        NSMutableArray *leadSalesRep = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mr Sales Rep", @"value", nil], nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadSalesRep forKey:@"field_salesrep"];

        // Set Lead request assets
        if([data objectForKey:@"savedAssets"]){
            NSMutableArray *leadRequestedAssets = [data objectForKey:@"savedAssets"];
            [requestDictionary setObject:leadRequestedAssets forKey:@"field_lead_requested_assets"];
        }
        else{
            NSMutableArray *leadRequestedAssets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"19841", @"nid", nil], nil];
            [requestDictionary setObject:leadRequestedAssets forKey:@"field_lead_requested_assets"];
        }

        // Set Lead og groups
        NSMutableDictionary *leadOgGroups = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:19018], @"19018", nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadOgGroups forKey:@"og_groups"];

        // Set Lead og gropus both
        NSMutableDictionary *leadOgGroupsBoth = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Sparksight", @"19018", nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadOgGroupsBoth forKey:@"og_groups_both"];

        // Set Lead webform
        NSMutableDictionary *leadWebform = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"true", @"addblock", nil];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadWebform forKey:@"webform"];

        // Set Lead og public
        BOOL leadOgPublic = false;
        [requestDictionary setObject:@"false" forKey:@"og_public"];

        // Set Lead taxonomy
        NSMutableArray *leadTaxonomy = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [requestDictionary setObject:leadTaxonomy forKey:@"taxonomy"];

        NSLog(@"Request Body: %@", requestDictionary);
```

The result printed from this is:

```
Request Body: {
    "field_badge_string" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_business_card" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_business_card_image" =     (
                {
            "" = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_add_1" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_add_2" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_city" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_company" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_contact" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_country" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_division" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_email" =     (
                {
            value = "michael@sparksight.com";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_event" =     (
                {
            nid = 19018;
        }
    );
    "field_lead_fax" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_first_name" =     (
                {
            value = Michael;
        }
    );
    "field_lead_job_title" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_last_name" =     (
                {
            value = Sigsbey;
        }
    );
    "field_lead_middle_name" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_notes" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_phone_1" =     (
                {
            value = 5129147975;
        }
    );
    "field_lead_phone_2" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_phonetic" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_qualification" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_requested_assets" =     (
                {
            nid = 19037;
        },
                {
            nid = 19035;
        },
                {
            nid = 19031;
        },
                {
            nid = 19021;
        },
                {
            nid = 20503;
        },
                {
            nid = 19351;
        },
                {
            nid = 19034;
        },
                {
            nid = 19033;
        },
                {
            nid = 19036;
        }
    );
    "field_lead_source" =     (
                {
            nid = 19018;
        }
    );
    "field_lead_state" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_status" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_subscribe" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_suffix" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_tags" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_title" =     (
                {
            value = "My Title";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_website" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_lead_zip" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_quiz_string" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_rfid_id" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_salesrep" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "field_services" =     (
                {
            value = "";
        }
    );
    "og_groups" =     {
        19018 = 19018;
    };
    "og_groups_both" =     {
        19018 = Sparksight;
    };
    "og_public" = "";
status = 1;
taxonomy =     (
            {
        "" = "";
    }
);
type = lead;
webform =     (
            {
        addblock = true;
    }
);
```

}

I can't figure out why I'm getting all these semicolons and parens as they are destroying my JSON formatting.  I can post the method that works (same process, different app), but really the issue is why is this formatting off?

Edit: Posted working code from previous app to show difference in output.

```
    NSMutableDictionary* resultPerson = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [resultPerson setObject:m_type forKey:@"type"];
    [resultPerson setObject:m_status forKey:@"status"];
    [resultPerson setObject:m_email forKey:@"field_lead_email"];

    if(m_source)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_source forKey:@"field_lead_source"];

    if(m_event)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_event forKey:@"field_lead_event"];

    if(m_tags)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_tags forKey:@"field_lead_tags"];

    if(m_title)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_title forKey:@"field_lead_title"];

    if(m_firstName)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_firstName forKey:@"field_lead_first_name"];

    if(m_lastName)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_lastName forKey:@"field_lead_last_name"];

    if(m_middleName)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_middleName forKey:@"field_lead_middle_name"];

    if(m_suffix)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_suffix forKey:@"field_lead_suffix"];

    if(m_jobTitle)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_jobTitle forKey:@"field_lead_job_title"];

    if(m_company)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_company forKey:@"field_lead_company"];

    if(m_division)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_division forKey:@"field_lead_division"];

    if(m_address1)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_address1 forKey:@"field_lead_add_1"];

    if(m_address2)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_address2 forKey:@"field_lead_add_2"];

    if(m_city)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_city forKey:@"field_lead_city"];

    if(m_state)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_state forKey:@"field_lead_state"];

    if(m_country)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_country forKey:@"field_lead_country"];

    if(m_phone1)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_phone1 forKey:@"field_lead_phone_1"];

    if(m_phone2)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_phone2 forKey:@"field_lead_phone_2"];

    if(m_fax)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_fax forKey:@"field_lead_fax"];

    if(m_website)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_website forKey:@"field_lead_website"];

    if(m_zip)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_zip forKey:@"field_lead_zip"];

    if(m_rfid)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_rfid forKey:@"field_rfid_id"];

    if(m_phonetic)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_phonetic forKey:@"field_lead_phonetic"];

    if(m_leadStatus)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_leadStatus forKey:@"field_lead_status"];

    if(m_bizCard)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_bizCard forKey:@"field_business_card"];

    if(m_bizCardImg)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_bizCardImg forKey:@"field_business_card_image"];

    if(m_qualification)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_qualification forKey:@"field_lead_qualification"];

    if(m_subscribe)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_subscribe forKey:@"field_lead_subscribe"];

    if(m_contact)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_contact forKey:@"field_lead_contact"];

    if(m_notes)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_notes forKey:@"field_lead_notes"];

    if(m_badge)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_badge forKey:@"field_badge_string"];

    if(m_quiz)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_quiz forKey:@"field_quiz_string"];

    if(m_services)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_services forKey:@"field_services"];

    if(m_salesRep)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_salesRep forKey:@"field_salesrep"];

    if(m_requestedAssets)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_requestedAssets forKey:@"field_lead_requested_assets"];

    if(m_ogGroups)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_ogGroups forKey:@"og_groups"];

    if(m_ogGroupsBoth)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_ogGroupsBoth forKey:@"og_groups_both"];

    if(m_webform)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_webform forKey:@"webform"];

    [resultPerson setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:m_ogPublic] forKey:@"og_public"];

    if(m_taxonomy)
        [resultPerson setObject:m_taxonomy forKey:@"taxonomy"];

    NSLog(@"Resulting Person data: %@", resultPerson);
```

With a result of:

```
{"status":"1","field_lead_first_name":[{"value":"2"}],"field_lead_zip":[{"value":""}],"field_lead_requested_assets":[{"nid":"19839"}],"field_lead_email":[{"value":"Test@test.com"}],"type":"lead","field_lead_title":[{"value":"Programmer"}],"og_public":0,"field_lead_last_name":[{"value":"Sigsbey"}],"field_lead_city":[{"value":"Austin"}],"field_lead_source":[{"nid":"19323"}],"field_lead_phone_1":[{"value":"5129147975"}],"field_lead_company":[{"value":"Sparksight"}],"field_lead_state":[{"value":"Tx"}],"field_lead_add_1":[{"value":""}]}
```

Comment: You're printing an `NSMutableDictionary` object rather than JSON. They are entirely different things. As for output formatting, it is a typical `NSDictionary` description.

Comment: In my previous app where I use this very same method, the printed statement comes out much different.  I am only printing a NSMutableDictionary there, too.  Went ahead and edited post above to show other output.

Comment: The object description (as produced by `-description` method) is an implementation detail useful only for debugging. It may change drastically between releases. What you _should_ do is compare JSON generated from these dictionaries.

Comment: I doubt very much whether using the `description` of an NS(Mutable)Dictionary can ever produce valid JSON.  The `description` of an NS(Mutable)Array comes close, though.  But if you want JSON you should use an object-to-JSON converter -- there are several good ones, or you can even write your own in less than 200 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out it wasn't the JSON parsing or the setup of the NSDictionary.  The issue ended up being server related (connections broken on the backend).  Thanks for all the help regardless!

Answer (score 1):

As comments have pointed out, the `NSLog` of a dictionary is not guaranteed to have any particular format. It therefore may change between iOS versions.

What you'd probably be best doing is:

- restricting yourself to iOS 5 and using Apple's `NSJSONSerialization` [`+dataWithJSONObject:options:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/dataWithJSONObject%3aoptions%3aerror%3a);
- using a third party JSON library to achieve the same thing on any version of iOS; or
- writing your own outputter based on the subset of objects that you're using.

If you're building the dictionary only to turn into JSON, you might even consider just building the JSON string instead of the dictionary.

Comment: No need to restrict yourself to iOS 5 -- there are several good non-Apple JSON implementations available.

Comment: @HotLicks Oh, sorry — poorly worded. the 'restricting yourself to iOS 5' is meant to attach only to the reference to Apple's NSJSONSerialization. I'll do a quick edit to make my construction clearer.